# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number, While Dynamically generating Columns in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` while creating grid using dynamic columns.

For a ref i have taken following jsbin and try to update column header `Balance` to `03/22/2016`.

http://jsbin.com/garifabuda/edit?html,js,output

Please make followoing changes in javascript and check error in console.

```
var data = [{
  "Name": "daya",
  "Role": "Developer",
  "Dept": "Dev",
  "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
  "03/22/2016": 23 // Previously it was Balance
}, {
  "Name": "siva",
  "Role": "Developer",
  "Dept": "Dev",
  "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
  "03/22/2016": 23 // Previously it was Balance
}, {
  "Name": "sivadaya",
  "Role": "Developer",
  "Dept": "Dev",
  "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
  "03/22/2016": 23 // Previously it was Balance
}, {
  "Name": "dayasiva",
  "Role": "Developer",
  "Dept": "Dev",
  "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
  "03/22/2016": 23 // Previously it was Balance
}];
```

Can anybody have any solution for this. I want column header as a date string.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

Here all columns are generated dynamically, so there might not be only "03/22/2016". It can be other dates also.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i have done some workaround, as kendo not supporting special chars (specifically /).

What i have done is,

1. Change the column name from db by adding `d_` and `X` and populate
   it. So now my column name is something like below

> d_03X22X2016

2. After that added following code in databound event of grid.

   ```
            dataBound: function (e) {

               var obj = $('.k-header .k-link');

               for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                   obj[i].innerHTML = obj[i].innerHTML.replace('d_', '').replace('X', '/').replace('X', '/');
               }
           }
   ```

It will replace all predefined(d_,X) special chars from view and shows as expected for me.
This is not perfect solution but kind of trick to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for you:

http://jsbin.com/yivufoduwo/1/edit?html,js,output

All I have done is added a `columns` collection to your model and then told the grid to use this for you columns:

I have changed the `generateModel` function to include this bit of code:

```
 if (property === "Balance") {
   columns.push({
     field: property,
     headerTemplate: "22/3/2016"
   });
 } else {
   columns.push({
     field: property,
     headerTemplate: property
   });
 }
```

this add's a new headerTemplate item to the column based on what you want it to be. This could be changed so that you have something else appear here of you could provide it an option that you passed into the function.

then in the grid initialization you just add the line:

`columns:model.columns`

hopefully this is what you were looking for.

By trying to use the date as a field name this breaks the naming system of the column which does not accept spaces or special characters.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, but i think i may have not convey requirement properly. I'm updating question little bit as data column is generating dynamically.

Comment: My statement still stands. I do something similar but even with dynamically generated columns I will provide the grid with a `definition` of what the column fields are and how they should be presented. All you need to do with your `source model` is include a property for the columns and if they should have a different column title then apply the header template. The fact you are including the *\\* for the column title is what is breaking the grid as it doesn't understand it. If you had your `dates field header`  in 'dd-MM-yyyy' then that should work.

Comment: I have tried your work around but it still not worked. I have created new fiddle to make it clean. https://jsfiddle.net/harshadray/ydmsbgno/ . Even applying '-' instead of '/' also not works.